# Unable to find a medium containing a live file system on second boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

**Before closing/marking this as duplicate read below first.**

Using a live ubuntu 14.04 LTS pen drive and various troubleshooting on similar posts I was able to ***successfully boot once but the mouse and keyboard were not working so I went for a reboot and after reboot again I got the unable to find live file system error message*** every time over and over again even after I created the bootable pen drive using the same steps.

MD5 hash is also correct.

Steps:-

I am using a Gigabyte ga-990fxa-ud3 rev 5 motherboard so I partitioned my 8GB pendrive into 2 parts each less than 4GB and created a bootable pen drive.I also disabled the USB 3.0, Because when I tried with only partitioned pen drive or disabling the USB 3.0 it did not work.

***NOTE:-*** I tried using the same pen drive with a laptop(hp pavilion p-077tx) of a friend and the pen drive works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the error, Since I partitioned the pen drive into two equal parts somewhat around 3850 MB each in windows but space calculations on Linux are done differently so, when I repartitioned the pen drive this time into 4-equal parts the bootable pen drive worked just fine.